# Signature capture in Web using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to capture signature from Ruby on Rails application and store it as image. Is there a suitable plugin for this in Ruby on Rails?

I want something like this in Ruby on Rails(I think this is in dot net):

http://www.realsignature.com/

http://www.realsignature.com/demo/default.aspx

I am using Rails 2.3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the **[signature-pad jQuery plugin](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad)** which uses canvas to capture the signture which you could then submit to your rails app via a form and then convert it to a png with **[chunkypng](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png/)** and store it using **[paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/)**.